# How to get the unique key of a Firebase database when one of its child is clicked in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase_database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2CBq.png)

[Card_view_android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5a29.png)

In my android app, the user creates events and details are sent to the firebase database. The event then is visible as a card view inside another activity.

I wish to make this as when the user clicks on +add me in that card, his details get added to that card. This part is ready, but I want his details to be pushed to the database as well. Can anyone help me?

```
FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = current_user.getUid();
DatabaseReference eventRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child("lists");
 String key = eventRef.push().getKey();

final DatabaseReference groupRef = eventRef.child("").child(key);
userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final String uName = dataSnapshot.child("member").getValue().toString();
        addMe.setText(uName);

        groupRef.child("members").setValue(uName).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Success Adding you in Event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "some error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
});
```

The above code just adds a member child below my firebase database. I wish to have it appended inside the key of the card view clicked.

Comment: Can you post your firebase database structure with your nodes please ?

Comment: Yes I have updated the question with  a image titled **Firebase_database**